# Import a Python package

Tags: python

I have a folder called `myPackage` which contains

- a file called `myModule.py`
- an empty file called `__init__.py`

The file `myModule.py` is as follows:

```
def foo():
    print("Hello!")
```

Now each of the following files would run smoothly and do what I expect:

First option:

```
import myPackage.myModule
myPackage.myModule.foo()
```

Second option:

```
from myPackage import myModule
myModule.foo()
```

Third option:

```
from myPackage.myModule import foo
foo()
```

My question is what happens if I run a script containing:

```
import myPackage
```

The import alone does make the interpreter complain... but then I would have expected the following to work:

```
myPackage.myModule1.foo()
```

which is *not* the case.

Can I do `import myPackage`? I guess so, since otherwise I would have gotten an error straight away...
What am I supposed to do next?

Comment: TL;DR: `import myPackage` imports `myPackage`, but not any submodules of it. If `myPackage` contains something like `from . import myModule`, then `myModule` is a name define in `myPackage` and is thus available as `myPackage.myModule` without doing anything else. If `myPackage` does *not* `import myModule`, then you can't access it, unless and until you `import` it explicitly.

Comment: @deceze sorry you lost me. how to can myPackage contain something like from . import myModule? myPackage is just a folder.

Comment: `__init__.py`...

Answer (score -1):

I usually write this to import customed packages:

`from myPackage import *`

The file is in the same folder as the file where I import it. I can the just call all the methods without putting everything in every command (so, not `myPackage.myModule1.foo()` but just `foo()`).

Comment: Please, avoid wildcard imports...

Comment: I'm sorry @ruslan_krivoshein, but what is a wildcard import?